# Removing entry from table

Tags: arrays, sdk, lua, coronasdk, lua-table

Can't remove an entry from table.

here's my code

```
dropItem = dropList[ math.random( #dropList ) ]
dropSomething[brick.index] = crackSheet:grabSprite(dropItem, true)
dropSomething[brick.index].x = brick.x
dropSomething[brick.index].y = brick.y
dropSomething[brick.index].name = dropItem
dropSomething[brick.index].type = "dropppedItems"
```

collision

```
function bounce(event)
        local item = event.other
        if item.type == "dropppedItems" then
            if item.name == "bomb" then
                Lives = Lives - 1
                LivesNum.text = tostring(Lives)
            end
        item:removeSelf();
        end     

end
```

What I've tried:

```
item:removeSelf(); -- removes the whole table
item = nil -- seems to do nothing, the object continue 
           -- to move and i still see the image
```

the only way i could remove the object from screen is by hiding it with
`transition.to(item, {time = 100, alpha = 0})`

Comment: What about `event.other = nil`?

Comment: i can only assume your function must be at the top of the event listener if not can you add another code for it

Answer (score 0):

There the item object should be a copy of your actual item. Means, it doesn't act like a pointer. So if you want to remove an item from the table, you should reach it within table.

You can modify your code like this :

```
dropItem = dropList[ math.random( #dropList ) ]
dropSomething[brick.index] = crackSheet:grabSprite(dropItem, true)
dropSomething[brick.index].x = brick.x
dropSomething[brick.index].y = brick.y
dropSomething[brick.index].name = dropItem
dropSomething[brick.index].type = "dropppedItems"
dropSomething[brick.index].id = brick.index

function bounce(event)
        local item = event.other
        if item.type == "dropppedItems" then
            if item.name == "bomb" then
                Lives = Lives - 1
                LivesNum.text = tostring(Lives)
            end
        dropSomething[item.id]:removeSelf();
        dropSomething[item.id] = nil
        end     
end
```

Assuming bounce function can reach dropSomething table

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to remove the object from the table, you can use the function 'table.remove()', which is very easy to use.

To do this, you have *two* ways:
One is to use a custom function, and other is to not.

I would recommend using a custom function.

To do that, you can do something like

```
    removeFromTable = function(tbl, lookfor)
       for i,v in pairs(tbl)do
          if(v.Name==lookfor)then -- change that to whatever you will use as a identification
             table.remove(tbl, i);
          end;
       end;
    end;
```

That would work assuming you're in RBLX_Lua. I am not sure if it works in other lua "versions". It needs you to have a identification "tag" for every object in the table, which you probably have considering it looks like you're making a game with items.

Hope it helps.